# How To Mock a .equal() method using easyMock

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have the following code segment to test inside if block

```
   if("anyString".equals("anyString")){
      //body
    }
```

How can I test above using easy mock as follows

lets take Chair as base class and getName() method which returns it name

```
expect(chair.getName()..eq("string")).andReturn(true);
```

it's throw an InvocationTargetException

Any Help Appreciated

Comment: Please provide a full example to get a better anwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two strings. There is no point in mocking a String. Your `expect` currently doesn't make sense Please see the [EasyMock documentation](https://easymock.org).

If we say that `chair` is a mock, and you want `getName()` to return `string`, it would be `expect(chair.getName()).andReturn("string");`

I don't think it is relevant to your question but not that `equals` can't be mocked. It's a special method used by EasyMock internally. `equals`, `toString` and `hashCode` can't be mocked.